# some questions about elmah

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah, elmah.mvc

I have just set up elmah in my MVC4 application and have some questions regarding it. Previously I rolled my own exception handling, so I am newbie to this.

Is it possible to set up elmah to log certain exceptions to either event log or/and text file? Or is something like nlog required for this to complement elmah?

When an exception occurs, I will redirect the user to an error page. I would like to include on the error page a unique id for the exception. That way I can get users to report an Id and I can check my logs as to what the error was. Does elmah create a unique id for errors? If so how can it be accessed. If not, would it be easy to add?

Finally, is it possible to add custom information to errors elmah captures? For example, on my system, all users are tagged with a unique id, can this be included with what is logged by elmah?

Comment: Why not just have the errors automatically emailed to you? If you are using Windows Authentication the users login will already be added to the exception record

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but this is not something I want to do.

Comment: What we setup on our application was log the errors and save them to the database, elmah gave us the ability to not only see who the logged in user was but additional information that the user isn't able to provide.  Once the error occurred the user is redirected to an "error" page where they can give additional information about what they were doing when the error occurred and we are given two sets of data to compare and find the issue. Remember the users may not know the technical backgrounds of the error but may give insight towards it.